# Intersections of a curve and a graph of function.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The function is $$f(x,y)=x^2 e^{xy} $$

I have found the tangent plane at (2,0,4) is given by $$4x + 8y - z =4$$

1. How do I find all points where the curve with parametric equation $$r(t)=(t,t^{-1},t^4)$$ meets the graph?
2. How do I find all points on the graph at which the vector (0, -e, 2) is normal to the tangent plane?

I'm a uni student and studying a multivariable calculus course without the proper prerequisites, so I'm struggling a bit. Any helps would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You know the equation of a tangent plane $8y +4-z=0.$  Here $(0,8,-1)$ are coordinates of a vector normal to this plane. This can help you to solve 2. For the question 1., simply put $(x,y,z)=(t,t^{-1},t^4)$ in the expression of the function, where $f(x,y)$ stands for $z.$